# File reading in C++ and eof

Tags: c++, file-io, eof

If I am reading a file in c++ like this:

```
//Begin to read a file
  FILE *f = fopen("vids/18.dat", "rb");
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
  long pos = ftell(f);
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

  char *m_sendingStream = (char*)malloc(pos);
  fread(m_sendingStream, pos, 1, f);
  fclose(f);
  //Finish reading a file
```

I have 2 questions first: Is this reading the entire file? (I want it to do so), and 2nd how can I create a while that continues until reaching the end of the file? I have:

`while(i < sizeof(m_sendingStream))`

but I am not sure if this works, I've been reading around (I've never programmed in c++ before) and I thought I could use `eof()` but apparently that's bad practice.

Comment: This is not c++, in fact this is C.

Comment: well I've had persons tell me it's c++ and some tell me it's C I really can't tell the difference yet.

Comment: This style of working with files is the C style.
Working with files in C++ would be mostly with the fstream library.
You can read more about working with files with C++ here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: Know that all standard C code is functionnal C++ code as well. C++ added over C.

Comment: @LuisArmando Thats because it is, in fact, perfectly valid C++. That it isn't using the C++ standard iostream library does not disqualify it as *not* C++, contrary to popular opinion. In fact, until C99 this *had* to be compiled with C++, as the inline variable declarations and single-line comments would puke on a standard C89 compiler.

Comment: @Julius Variable length array declarations not withstanding. VLAs are still not in C++, likely never will be, but is supported (but not required) by the C99 standard. Apart from that, you're correct afaik.

Comment: I thought 'backwards' compatibility with C was a well established, core feature of  C++. I'm just a senior undergrad (if that means anything), please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

A loop should not be necessary when reading from a file, since you will get the entire contents with your code in one go. You should still record and check the return value, of course:

```
size_t const n = fread(buf, pos /*bytes in a record*/, 1 /*max number of records to read*/, f);

if (n != 1) { /* error! */ }
```

You can also write a loop that reads until the end of the file without knowing the file size in advance (e.g. read from a pipe or growing file):

```
#define CHUNKSIZE 65536
char * buf = malloc(CHUNKSIZE);
{
   size_t n = 0, r = 0;

   while ((r = fread(buf + n, 1 /*bytes in a record*/, CHUNKSIZE /*max records*/, f)) != 0)
   {
      n += r;

      char * tmp = realloc(buf, n + CHUNKSIZE);

      if (tmp) { buf = tmp; }
      else     { /* big fatal error */ }
   }

   if (!feof(f))
   {
      perror("Error reading file");
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand so I can add the if inside the while?

Comment: @LuisArmando: There's no "while". Either you have a single check like I do, or you write a loop (but then there's no "if").

Comment: so I can add your `size_t const ...` line before my `long pos = ...` line and then I can just either use a single check like you do or a loop checking that `n != pos` did I get it right?

Comment: @LuisArmando: Well, no. The single check goes instead of your existing `fread` line. But I've also added a hypothetical loop. Just mind that it's really completely pointless.

Comment: @LuisArmando: Why not ask the author of the other question? Or read the manual and check for yourself?

Comment: NO, `fread` will not return the number of bytes read but the number of *records* read. Since `fread` is called to read 1 record (`count` = `1`) `pos` bytes in size (`size` = `pos`), the return value (if successful) will be 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is the C style of working with files, the C++ style would be using the [`fstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) library.

And about your second question, a good way to check wether you are on the end of the file or not, would be to use the [`feof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/) function.

Comment: No, he will not read 1 byte, he will read *exactly* 1 `pos`-byte large record.